# Firebase configration is crashing in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

App is crashing while configure firebase,Unable to resolve

Error:libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import CoreData
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift


    let mainUrl = "https://gopolly.com/well.php/"

    @UIApplicationMain class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        var window: UIWindow?


        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
        {

            FirebaseApp.configure()
           IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable=true

            return true
        }
```

[image]

Comment: may i see the hole error log?

Comment: please check qstn ..thanks for response

Comment: Are you sure it is Firebase that is causing the crash? I have had IQKeyboardManager crash my app on startup before, so this might also be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the application works without Firebase. Delete or comment out the lines of connection to the Firebase.
2. If the application is working without errors, then go back to the initial code and check the GoogleService-Info.plist. The BUNDLE_ID must be the same as the Bundle Identifier of the application.